# Passing a func as parameter

Tags: c#

I have this function I am trying to implement. But what is the last parameter? Some kind of delegate and how do you add that?

[image]

Comment: [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-5.0). It's a delegate which accepts nothing and returns a string. So e.g. `() => "foo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the name of a function, such as `MyFunction`, that has no inputs and returns a string

```
string MyFunction()
{
    return "string";
}
```

or use a lambda expression such as `() => "string"`

Comment: Thanks. But that would be me providing the token, and I would expect to get one back?

Comment: This is a different question then what your original question was asking.